# Darboux theorem condition for it being applicable

Tags: calculus

Darboux theorem which states a function : $f(x)$ in some bounded interval $[a,b]$  such that it has derivative (infinite/finite) at every point on the interval , then if $f'(a) <f'(b)$ , there exists c in [a,b]  such that $f'(c) = d$  where d lies in between [ f'(a),f'(b)]

> When applying it for $f(x) = |x|$ in the interval $-1$ to $1$ , as such if applied without conditon it has $f'(1) = 1$ and $f'(-1) = -1$ so it says there exists c such that $f'(x) = 0$ but we know it doesnt have that value at all. What additional restriction is there?

Comment: Sure i will add

Comment: $f$ needs to be differentiable on the interval. Your $f$ is not differentiable at the origin.

Comment: Another function to consider for your theorem on $[-1,1]$ is $$x \mapsto x^{1/3}$$

Comment: @peek-a-boo can you tell the correct statement fully ? For darboux applicability i will accept that as answer

Comment: Does it fails there ? @311411

Comment: The cube root function? Well, check each hypothesis of your theorem for it.